# Gstreamer warning GStreamer-CRITICAL **: _gst_util_uint64_scale_int: assertion 'num >= 0' failed

Tags: gstreamer

I develop an audio player which uses following Gstreamer pipeline:

> appsrc ! mpegaudioparse ! queue ! mad ! volume ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink

The application works. However, sometimes it notifies some annoying warning messsages as follows:

> GStreamer-CRITICAL **: _gst_util_uint64_scale_int: assertion 'num >= 0' failed
>   xcb_connection_has_error() returned true

I don't call the gst_util_uint64_scale_int() in my application.
Here is version of Gstreamer and plugin I used:
gstreamer1.0(1.8.3)
gstreamer1.0-plugins-base(1.8.3)
gstreamer1.0-plugins-good(1.8.3)
gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly(1.8.3)
gstreamer1.0-alsa(1.8.3)
gstreamer1.0-pulseaudio(1.8.3)

I already spent much time to solve this issue but have not found out the cause.
If anybody knows a reason of these warning messages, please help.

**Update #2**: When I set GST_DEBUG=fatal_criticals and run my player inside GDB, I got following stack trace:

```
[New Thread 0xaa01cb40 (LWP 22656)]
Thread 149 "source:src" received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
[Switching to Thread 0xab82fb40 (LWP 22655)]
0xb7878749 in g_logv () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0xb7878749 in g_logv () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#1  0xb7878805 in g_log () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#2  0xb7878839 in g_return_if_fail_warning () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#3  0xb7a53ed6 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0
#4  0xb7545910 in gst_base_parse_push_frame () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0
#5  0xb7549fbd in gst_base_parse_finish_frame () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0
#6  0xb518158e in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstaudioparsers.so
#7  0xb75419f5 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0
#8  0xb7546a67 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0
#9  0xb7a169df in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0
#10 0xb7a1e98c in gst_pad_push () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0
#11 0xb755f393 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstbase-1.0.so.0
#12 0xb7a497ca in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0
#13 0xb7a4a767 in ?? () from /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgstreamer-1.0.so.0
#14 0xb7899a64 in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#15 0xb789900a in ?? () from /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglib-2.0.so.0
#16 0xb7814295 in start_thread (arg=0xab82fb40) at pthread_create.c:333
#17 0xb7d50eee in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S:114
(gdb)
```

Comment: I could sove the issue "xcb_connection_has_error() returned true". Such warning happens beause I did a setting in my shell script which invokes the player. Here is the setting which causes the warning: export DISPLAY=0:0

Comment: You can get a stack trace by setting `G_DEBUG=fatal_criticals` so it will cause your program to interrupt when that happens. Run it inside `gdb` with that environment variable set and install debug symbols for gstreamer. This way you can pinpoint who is causing the assertion and where it happens.

Comment: @thiagoss: Thank you for your help. I could get the stack trace as you said. It seems this warning relates to the mpegaudioparse. FYI, After playing serveral song without unrefering the pipeline. This warning happens.

Comment: solved the issue?

Comment: @Sam: Not yet. I did workaround by unrefering  the pipeline  after playing 2 audio files. Then, there is no warning. FYI, if you remove the "mpegaudioparse " from the pipeline, there is no issue. However, without the parser, It could not play some mp3 streams.